# Analyzing Time Complexity in a for loop

Tags: performance, time, time-complexity

I wanted to ask why some people say that we should multiply what is in the for loop with *n*, others say we must multiply with *n* and then add "1" because we have that stop statement, for example i < n.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i ++){
    // Code
}
```

So, some say that we have to multiply the `Code` with "n", because it repeats n times, and let it like this, so we would have TimeInsideLoop*n time for the loop, which is O(n). 
Others say that we have to add 1 after we multiply, because of that last comparison between i and n `i < n` at the end, that stops the loop, so we would have TimeInsideLoop*n+1 for the loop.

But my question is, if we want to be so precise when we do the time complexity why don't we add TimeInsideLoop*n + 2, because we have `i = 0` at the beginning.

So we would have the TimeInsideLoop for the `//Code`, mutliplied with n, because it will happen ***n times***, and then for the last comparison, we would add another "1" because it is constant time, and because at the beginning of the loop we declared a new variable `i = 0`  we add another 1, so we would have TimeInsideLoop*n+2.

Comment: Being exact here is usually impossible to do. Even in this simple code, the truce is you have no idea what will the exact time complexity actually be. Many compilers do optimizations such as [loop unrolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling), that changes your calculations completely. And the developer usually has little information on which optimizations exactly are being performed.

Comment: So, then does it really matter if we write TimeInsideLoop*n + 1 or +2 or , we just multiply it with n and let it like that ? Because in some tutorials they write *n + 1, in some they only write *n and I don't really know what's correct and what's not

Comment: To do so, you need to define very well what you are counting (number of memory accesses? Number of comparisons? number of flops?). And even then, in real life, due to compiler optimizations - your theoretic 100% correct analysis will be wrong.